# How memory fragmentation is avoided in Swift

Tags: swift, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

GC's compaction, sweep and mark avoids heap memory fragmentation. So how is memory fragmentation is avoided in Swift?

Are these statements correct?

1. Every time a reference count becomes zero, the allocated space gets added to an 'available' list.
2. For the next allocation, the frontmost chunk of memory which can fit the size is used.
3. Chunks of previously used up memory will be used again to be best extent possible

Is the 'available list'  sorted by address location or size?

Will live objects be moved around for better compaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some digging in the assembly of a compiled Swift program, and I discovered that [`swift:: swift_allocObject`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp#L47) is the runtime function called when a new Class object is instantiated. It calls [`SWIFT_RT_ENTRY_IMPL(swift_allocObject)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp#L58) which calls [`swift::swift_slowAlloc`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/Heap.cpp#L26), which ultimately calls... `malloc()` from the C standard library. So Swift's runtime isn't doing the memory allocation, it's `malloc()` that does it.

`malloc()` is implemented in the C library (`libc`). You can see Apple's implementation of `libc` [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/gen/). `malloc()` is defined in [`/gen/malloc.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/gen/malloc.c). If you're interested in exactly what memory allocation algorithm is used, you can continue the journey down the rabbit hole from
there.

> Is the 'available list' sorted by address location or size?

That's an implementation detail of `malloc` that I welcome you to discover in the source code linked above.

> **1.** Every time a reference count becomes zero, the allocated space gets added to an 'available' list.

Yes, that's correct. Except the "available" list might not be a list. Furthermore, this action isn't necessarily done by the Swift runtime library, but it could be done by the OS kernel through a system call.

> **2.** For the next allocation, the frontmost chunk of memory which can fit the size is used.

Not necessarily frontmost. There are many different memory allocation schemes. The one you've thought of is called "first fit". Here are some example memory allocation techniques (from [this site](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/%7Ecsonline/OS/Lessons/MemoryAllocation/index.html)):

> - **Best fit:** The allocator places a process in the smallest block of unallocated memory in which it will fit. For example, suppose a process requests 12KB of memory and the memory manager currently has a list of unallocated blocks of 6KB, 14KB, 19KB, 11KB, and 13KB blocks. The best-fit strategy will allocate 12KB of the 13KB block to the process.
> - **First fit:** There may be many holes in the memory, so the operating system, to reduce the amount of time it spends analyzing the available spaces, begins at the start of primary memory and allocates memory from the first hole it encounters large enough to satisfy the request. Using the same example as above, first fit will allocate 12KB of the 14KB block to the process.
> - **Worst fit**: The memory manager places a process in the largest block of unallocated memory available. The idea is that this placement will create the largest hold after the allocations, thus increasing the possibility that, compared to best fit, another process can use the remaining space. Using the same example as above, worst fit will allocate 12KB of the 19KB block to the process, leaving a 7KB block for future use.

Objects will not be compacted during their lifetime. The `libc` handles memory fragmentation by the way it allocates memory. It has no way of moving around objects that have already been allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Alexander’s answer is great, but there are a few other details somewhat related to memory layout.  Garbage Collection requires memory overhead for compaction, so the wasted space from malloc fragmentation isn’t really putting it at much of a disadvantage.  Moving memory around also has a hit on battery and performance since it invalidates the processor cache.  Apple’s memory management implementation can compress memory that hadn’t been accessed in awhile.  Even though virtual address space can be fragmented, the actual RAM is less fragmented due to compression.  The compression also allows faster swaps to disk.

Less related, but one of the big reasons Apple picked reference counting has more to do with c-calls then memory layout.  Apple’s solution works better if you are heavily interacting with c-libraries.  A garbage collected system is normally in order of magnitude slower interacting with c since it needs to halt garbage collection operations before the call.  The overhead is usually about the same as a syscall in any language.  Normally that doesn’t matter unless you are calling c functions in a loop such as with OpenGL or SQLite.  Other threads/processes can normally use the processor resources while a c-call is waiting for the garbage collector so the impact is minimal if you can do your work in a few calls.  In the future there may be advantages to Swift’s memory management when it comes to system programming and a rust-like lifecycle memory management.  It is on Swift’s roadmap, but Swift 4 is not yet suited for systems programming.  Typically in C# you would drop to managed c++ for systems programming and operations that make heavy use of c libraries.